# How to mutiple form login in spring security and custom request login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two server : 
server1 : login by email and password
server2 : login by phone and passcode

i want two server login in spring security . I want server 1  login with url `server1/login` and server2 logn `server2/login` in spring security. I write spring security look like:

```
    http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()

                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin() 
                .loginProcessingUrl("/server1/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler) 
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler) 
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/server2/login")
                .usernameParameter("phone")
                .successHandler()

                .permitAll();
```

But it not work.

I want move loginProcessingUrl("/server1/login") => to controller and validate it(validate email and password, search email and check some information database). It same to server 2. 
Move loginProcessingUrl("/server2/login") => to controller and validate it(by phone and password,search email and check information database 
 => it possible?

I have two question

1. How to mutiple login in spring security with two server: server1 login by(email and password) and server 2 login by(phone and passcode).  When server call login it redirect to login by email and server 2 login it call login by phone.
2. How to custom api login spring. Because spring default login by username and password. I want login by phone and passcode. How to create custom api login in controller and handle login by each server. Because if i create custom api, i can't detect when user login success. But when i using `loginProcessingUrl("/server1/login")` spring auto detect it by AuthenticationSuccessHandler. Thanks you

Comment: I think you cannot have multiple formLogin in the same config. Add a new implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with a separate pattern and `Order` (for example `/server1` in the default config (order = default 100) and `/server2` in a new config (order = 50), something like this: https://dzone.com/articles/example-of-multiple-login-pages-with-spring-securi

Comment: So i can custom form login by phone instead of email and i can change url /login into my controller. Example /server1/login and validate it . It possible?

Comment: On second thought, you don't need separate implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I think a single `formLogin()` will work. You should keep the generic names for username and password in the login form something like `.usernameParameter("login_id").passwordParameter("password")` and validate the phone or email (value of "login_id") during the authentication process. Reason is that `loginProcessingUrl` is used by spring security filters.